# Limits of Functions proof $\lim_{x\to 5} \left(x^2-3x+1\right)=11$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

Prove that $$\lim_{x\to 5} \left(x^2-3x+1\right) = 11$$

How would you pick your $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ for the proof?  I know you have to use the limit definition, but I am struggling to begin the proof.

Comment: I just fixed it. It has to converge to 11

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x^2-3x+1$ and note that $f(5)=11$. We have to bound
$$
|x^2-3x+1-11|=|x-5||x+2|
$$
We want to make this less than epsilon. To control the term $|x+2|$, assume that $\delta<1$ (for example) i.e. $4<x<6$ and bound $|x+2|$. Let $D$ be this bound. Then take $\delta$ to be the minimum of $\epsilon/D$ and $1$.

Comment: Why do we want to control |x+2| and not |x-5|?

Comment: NTT it's possible that you've never done something like "take $\delta$ to be the minimum...". Just try starting your proof like this and everything will fall into place: "Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\delta = \min(1, \epsilon/8)$". This tells you that $\delta$ must be less than or equal to both $1$ and $\epsilon/8$, so you have more to work with. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of polynomials and rational functions, take a look at and try to simplify

$$\left\vert \frac{f(x)-L}{x-a}\right\lvert$$

and find an upper bound $B$ on the value of the expression for

$$ a-1<x<a+1 $$

Then let $\delta=\min\left\{1,\dfrac{\epsilon}{B}\right\}$.

In this example, we expect the limit to be $L=11$, so we simplify

$$\left\vert \frac{x^2-3x+1-11}{x-5}\right|$$

which simplifies to

$$\left\vert x+2\right\vert$$

so we want to find an upper bound $B$ on $\vert x+2\vert$ when $5-1<x<5+1$.

But if $4<x<6$ then $6<x+2<8$. So we can conclude that $\vert x+2\vert<8$ when $\vert x-5\vert<1$.

So $B=8$. Now we have finished our preliminaries and are ready to begin our proof.

Let $\epsilon>0$.  Then let $\delta=\min\left\{1,\dfrac{\epsilon}{8}\right\}$and $\vert x-5|<\delta$.

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
\vert x^2-3x+1-11\vert &=& \vert x-5\vert\cdot\vert x+2\vert\\
&<&\frac{\epsilon}{8}\cdot 8\\
&=&\epsilon
\end{eqnarray}